# Mole Fraction and Atom Fraction

Tags: mole

I'm probably overthinking this but would appreciate a peer check.

Mole fraction of element $i$ in compound: $\frac{\mathcal{M}_i}{\mathcal{M}}$

I used script M so as not to confuse with molar mass (often denoted as capital M).

Atom fraction of element $i$ in compound: $\frac{N_i}{N}$

Now, if Avogadro's number is atoms/mol then isn't the mole fraction equal to the atom fraction?

$$
\frac{N_i}{N}\frac{[\text{atom}]}{[\text{atom}]} \cdot \frac{N_a}{N_a}\frac{[\text{atom}/\text{mol}]}{[\text{atom}/\text{mol}]} = \frac{\mathcal{M}_i}{\mathcal{M}} \frac{[\text{mol}]}{[\text{mol}]}\\
\frac{N_a}{N_a}=1\\
\frac{N_i}{N}=\frac{\mathcal{M}_i}{\mathcal{M}}
$$

Comment: Usually the mole fraction is mostly used in studying mixtures of different substances, like the osmotic pressure of sugar solutions, for example, or the partial pressure of Oxygen in air. Atom fraction is mostly used when determining the formula of a pure compound. by elementary analysis. In water the atom fraction of hydrogen is 2/3. Atom fraction can also be used to describe the composition of complex mixtures, like the elements in Earth, or in the human body.

Comment: The mole fraction and atom fraction will be the same only if you are clearly talking about *atoms*. But this is often *not* what is being talked about in typical chemistry conversations. We might talk about the moles of sodium and the moles of sulfate in sodium sulphate, for example. If you always specify moles of *what* then you are OK but that if often not done and this leads to ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The fallacy lies in the assumption that mole fraction and the number fraction are always the same.

For example, take $\ce{Na2SO4}$

what is the atom fraction of Na: 2/(2+1+4) = 2/7

What about the mole fraction of Na? It 2$N_A$/$N_A$(2+1+4)= 2/7

However, this "simple" formula of yours breaks down in the case of mixtures even if we mix them in 1:1 mol ratio. Calculate the mol fraction of Na ions in a mixture using your formula for $\ce{NaCl}$ and $\ce{Na2SO4}$ and see that you will not get the right answer.